# Что нужно для создания соц сети на Android

Tags: java, android

Есть проект, пока на стадии идеи, это что-то типо университетской социальной сети, подскажите пожалуйста что нужно для создания такого рода приложения, с какими трудностями можно столкнуться.

Comment: просто ВКонтакте

Comment: что просто ВКонткте?

Comment: зачем что-то создавать, когда уже есть более мощный аналог твоей идеи

Comment: это нужно не для общей публикации, просто есть необходимость в данном приложении

Comment: Необходимости в приложении не бывает. Бывает необходимость в решении им неких задач. Какие задачи вы хотите решить?

Comment: у меня проектная работа, написать приложения в виде соц сети, надо ее реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сам новичок. Но попробуйте с чего-то простого. Начните с приложения для общения с другом, потом развивайте. Самое плохое для программиста - реализовать сразу какую-то идею, сколь большой она не была. Задачу всегда стоит разбивать на подзадачи. Если не согласны, то готовьтесь учить саму Java, Android SDK, HTTP и шифрование.

Comment: да, так и хочу начать с простого, просто пока честно говоря не имею представления с чего начать, что учить, может посоветуете какие либо учебники?

Comment: "Философия Java" Брюс Эккель
И рекомендую обращаться к самой документации по SDK, там очень много всего полезного. Посмотрите уроки под Android, коих много - startandroid, блог Александра Климова. И на самом stackoverflow есть много решенных проблем.

Comment: спасибо за помощь